# Does GTK4 support Apple's silicon chips?

Tags: c, cmake, gtk, clion, gtk4

I've been trying for about an hour to install GTK4 to my OSX system, to try and make a GUI in C, and have been failing miserably.

My issue is this: GTK4 is installed via Brew and GTK's installation script, but still I cannot include `<gtk/gtk.h>`. This is my CMakeLists file:

```c
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(simulation C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK4 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk4)

add_executable(simulation src/main.c
        src/sim.h)

target_link_libraries(simulation gtk4)
```

This compiles just fine, and CMake accepts it, but I still cannot import absolutely any files from the GTK library.

I'm on a 2023 M2 MacBook pro, using CLion.

Comment: Does a fike named gtk.h exist anywhere on your system? What is the full path to it?

Comment: The call to `pkg_check_modules(GTK4 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk4)` creates imported target named `PkgConfig::GTK4`, so you need to use it in the `target_link_libraries` call: `target_link_libraries(simulation PRIVATE PkgConfig::GTK4)`.